# What is the most typical instruction for this type of questions?

Tags: expressions

What is the most typical instruction for this type of questions?

```
A. I go __ school.
B. I want to give this __ you.

a. to     b.at
```

I mean, how is this?

```
"Q. Choose the one that is appropriate for the two blanks in common."
```

Comment: It's not a very common sort of question, so I hesitate to describe any instruction as 'typical'. I would say "Choose the preposition which would be appropriate in both blanks, not just one."

Answer (score 2):

You could convert this into something called a *matching* question. You will usually see these presented in columns, like this:

[image]

For the directions, you might say something like:

> *Choose the preposition from Column B that best fits in the sentence in Column A*.

It's considered a best practice to set up the question such that some items may be used more than once, and others not at all, and to specifically mention that in the directions.

Test writing tips are off-topic, but you can read more about matching questions at sites like [this one](http://theelearningcoach.com/elearning_design/writing-matching-test-items/). You should be able to Google something like `tips for writing matching questions` to get a lot more advice from experts.

---

If you want one answer to work for both sentences, that's simply a multiple-choice question:

I would write the directions like this:

> *Choose the preposition that best fits into both sentences*.

Of course, if you have more than two sentences, you would need to change the word *both* to *all*.

[image]

Comment: @StoneyB - Ah! I see. I'll amend my answer.